Different results produced by FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform
I try to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of
(k2^2 - k1^2)/(k1^2 + k2^2) using FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform:
FourierTransform[(k2^2 - k1^2)/(k1^2 + k2^2), {k1, k2}, {x1, x2}, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]
(* -DiracDelta[x1] DiracDelta[x2] + 1/2 ((2 (x1^2 - x2^2) (HeavisideTheta[-x1] + HeavisideTheta[x1]))/(\[Pi] (x1^2 + x2^2)^2) - I Sign[x1] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][I x1 - x2] - I Sign[x1] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][I x1 + x2]) *)

InverseFourierTransform[(k2^2 - k1^2)/(k1^2 + k2^2), {k1, k2}, {x1, x2}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
(* -DiracDelta[x1] DiracDelta[x2] *)

Why do they produce different results? Is it a bug?
(I used version 14.0.0 for Windows 64-bit)

In my version, "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)", these yield the same result. What version are you using? (Evaluate $Version and include that .)

Confirm these results in 14.0 on Windows 10 and Linux.

It should be noticed that both transforms do not exist as usual transforms because RealAbs[(k2^2 - k1^2)/(k1^2 + k2^2)] is not integrable over the plane $k1,k2$.

something more. If we do the 1-D FourierTransform twice, we get same result as expected. i.e. FourierTransform[(k2^2-k1^2)/(k1^2+k2^2),k1,x1,FourierParameters->{-1,1}]; FourierTransform[%,k2,x2,FourierParameters->{-1,1}] gives same output you show.  But if we do the same for the InverseFourierTransform now the result is not the same as before. It still does not match the first result though. InverseFourierTransform[(k2^2-k1^2)/(k1^2+k2^2),k1,x1,FourierParameters->{1,-1}]; InverseFourierTransform[%,k2,x2,FourierParameters->{1,-1}]

btw, to get the exact same result from both calls,  add $Assumptions=x1>0;. Now FourierTransform and InverseFourierTransform give same result.
